# Java EE tutorial Examples failing with following error

Tags: java, maven, glassfish

I have downloaded and Java EE SDK from Java Tutorials. According to tutorials, It we had to integrate this SDK with netbeans, but Netbeans 7 was not able to find my GlassFish server. So, I installed Netbeans with Glassfish at the same location as specified in Tutorial i.e. C:\glassfish4. And, then I copied docs folder from SDK to this installation and trying to build, but it is failing

```
[INFO]                                                                                                                          
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ helloservice-war ---                                   
[INFO] No sources to compile                                                                                                    
[INFO]                                                                                                                          
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ helloservice-war ---                                              
[INFO] No tests to run.                                                                                                         
[INFO]                                                                                                                          
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) @ helloservice-war ---                                                        
[INFO] Packaging webapp                                                                                                         
[INFO] Assembling webapp [helloservice-war] in [C:\glassfish4\docs\javaee-tutorial\examples\jaxws\helloservice-war\target\hellos
ervice-war]                                                                                                                     
[INFO] Processing war project                                                                                                   
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\glassfish4\docs\javaee-tutorial\examples\jaxws\helloservice-war\src\main\webapp]            
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [42 msecs]                                                                                           
[INFO] Building war: C:\glassfish4\docs\javaee-tutorial\examples\jaxws\helloservice-war\target\helloservice-war.war             
[INFO]                                                                                                                          
[INFO] --- cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.4:redeploy (deploy) @ helloservice-war ---                                                   
[INFO] [DeployerRedeployMojo] Resolved container artifact org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-container-glassfish:jar:1.4.4 for contai
ner glassfish4x                                                                                                                 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Authentication failed for user: admin                                                             
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Command deploy failed.                                                                            
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] with password from password file: C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/password.properties             
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] (Usually, this means invalid user name and/or password)                                           
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                 
[INFO] Reactor Summary:                                                                                                         
[INFO]                                                                                                                          
[INFO] jaxws ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.470 s]                                                  
[INFO] helloservice-war .................................. FAILURE [  3.219 s]                                                  
[INFO] hello-appclient ................................... SKIPPED                                                              
[INFO] hello-webclient ................................... SKIPPED                                                              
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE                                                                                                            
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                 
[INFO] Total time: 4.257 s                                                                                                      
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-19T14:51:43+05:30                                                                                   
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/226M                                                                                                   
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.4:redeploy (deploy) on project helloservice-war: Execu
tion deploy of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.4:redeploy failed: GlassFish admin command failed: asadmin exited
 1 -> [Help 1]                                                                                                                  
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.4:rede
ploy (deploy) on project helloservice-war: Execution deploy of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.4:redeploy failed
: GlassFish admin command failed: asadmin exited 1                                                                              
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)                                      
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)                                      
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)                                      
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)             
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)              
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
                at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution deploy of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.4:redeploy failed: GlassFish admin command failed: asadmin exited 1
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:144)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: GlassFish admin command failed: asadmin exited 1
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.glassfish.internal.GlassFish3xAsAdmin.invokeAsAdmin(GlassFish3xAsAdmin.java:88)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.glassfish.internal.AbstractGlassFishInstalledLocalContainer.invokeAsAdmin(AbstractGlassFishInstalledLocalContainer.java:96)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.glassfish.internal.AbstractGlassFishInstalledLocalContainer.invokeAsAdmin(AbstractGlassFishInstalledLocalContainer.java:69)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.glassfish.GlassFish3xInstalledLocalDeployer.doDeploy(GlassFish3xInstalledLocalDeployer.java:89)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.glassfish.internal.AbstractGlassFishInstalledLocalDeployer.redeploy(AbstractGlassFishInstalledLocalDeployer.java:97)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.DeployerRedeployMojo.performDeployerActionOnSingleDeployable(DeployerRedeployMojo.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractDeployerMojo.performDeployerActionOnAllDeployables(AbstractDeployerMojo.java:166)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractDeployerMojo.doExecute(AbstractDeployerMojo.java:97)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractCargoMojo.execute(AbstractCargoMojo.java:432)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
        ... 20 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem solved. Netbeans 7 has a problem with the Glassfish server that comes with Oracle SDK. So, I didn't add it to the Netbeans and manually started server and Database from command line and built the project again.

```
asadmin start-domain --verbose
asadmin start-database
```

After this, Projects are building perfectly.